# How to go back to application after opened URL in inAppbrowser in Phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, html-framework-7

I am developing a phonegap integrated with Framework7 application for android and when I opened an URL in inAppbrowser its worked fine but after opened it in inAppbrowser how to go back to app home page when I click on back button not an android hardware back button.

Below is the code:

```
<form onsubmit="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('url', '_blank',  'location=no'); return false;" method="post" >                                 
    <center><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">                                    
</form>
```

And for go back to app code is as shown below:

```
<input type="submit" id="bck" value="Done">

<script>     

  $(document).on("click touchstart", '#bck', function() {
      window.location = "index.html"; //if i give like this it goes to index page but no functions will work
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue can you help me on this?